# mesa concerns January 2018

Tags: desktop-environments

Can anyone advise on the status of the recent mesa issue after an update January 4th or 5th, 2018?
If it was update related what is a normal time frame for resolution?
Noob getting his feet wet with Ubuntu!
Thanks for your time.
GordK

follow up...I followed the suggestions in that answer prior to placing my question. I jumped ahead to the 17.3 ppa as per that answer. Things are OK for now. I see there will be a fix released for this issue. I will watch for that fix and get back on track with regular sourced updates. Thanks for your time!
GordK

190118 Thanks for the follow up on this issue. I have been checking on progress and just saw that the issue has been resolved. I have updated to remove the 17.3 work around and rebooted and did the suggested update. Things look solid. Thanks again for your time and expertise!
GordK